# Python Regex - Efficient before OR after in date

Tags: python, regex, date

I'm trying to write a date regex in Python. While I have a working regex it seems overly complex, but I'm not sure how to change the logic so that the date numbers can come before OR after the month. For example a date can be written as:

```
12 December 2014
```

or

```
December 12 2014
```

A basic regex for capturing the first date would be:

```
re.compile(r'\d{1,2}\s+(?:November|December)(?:\s+\d{2,4})?
```

To capture the second one I could use:

```
re.compile(r'(?:November|December)\s+\d{1,2}\s+(?:\s+\d{2,4})?
```

How could I combine these into a single regex such that the date number (12) can only appear a single time, before or after the month name?

Answer (score 1):

```
re.compile(r'((\d{1,2}\s+(?:November|December))|((?:November|December)\s+\d{1,2}\s+))(?:\s+\d{2,4})?')
```